# How do I find out about the update history in Ubuntu distribution update channels?

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, pulseaudio

I run 20.04 (Focal Fossa).

Specifically I would like to know when (and if) I receive an update in the `pulseaudio` package. ([A bug was fixed](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/507), and they have made a [release with the bugfix](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/tags/v14.99.1).)

To get a gist of my chances of receiving the update, I would like to know when previous updates to the `pulseaudio` package happened in my distribution (20.04 Focal Fossa).

I looked around at `archive.ubuntu.com`, and noticed it only took a few days for a release to be included there the previous time:

- https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/tags/v14.2 (the release)
- http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/ (you can see it was added a few days later)

But I don't think this shows when it is included in my distribution's update channel.

Is there any way to get a version release history of the registry? Is this archived somewhere in a git repository that I'm unaware of?

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I am capable of answering the first two questions myself with `apt list --installed | grep pulseaudio`. Answer: I still run `1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.10` currently. And this is also the latest version in the `focal-updates` channel. What I want to know is: When did this version (and previous versions) arrive in the `focal-updates` channel, so that I can make an (admittedly inaccurate) estimate of when I will receive the bug fix.

Comment: I hope I understand correct. `apt changelog pulseaudio`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I wasn't aware of the `changelog` command in `apt`. If you post this as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the whole changelog info from any installed packages (that support it) with apt itself:

```
apt changelog <name of package>
```

for better reading use less because the output can be long.

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered my own question. The following page shows the updates that landed in the focal package:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+source/pulseaudio/+changelog

This would also work for other packages by simply replacing `pulseaudio` with your package of choice.

Comment: Also https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/pulseaudio has *Ubuntu Changelog* [link](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/pulseaudio_14.2-1ubuntu1/changelog). Using packages.ubuntu.com is easier that laucnhpad.